# Polynomials with exponents in numerical semigroup

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, semigroups, group-rings

When thinking about monoid algebras (semigroup rings), I came across the following:

Let $S$ be a numerical semigroup, i.e., an additively closed subset of $\mathbb{N}_0$ containing $0$ such that $\mathbb{N}_0 \setminus S$ is finite. Let $K$ be any field.

**Question:** Do there exist polynomials $a, h \in K[x]$ with $a(0) = h(0) = 1$ and $a$ has only exponents in $S$ such that their product $ah$ has only exponents in $(\mathbb{N}_0 \setminus S) \cup \{0\}$.

Say, $a=1+k_{s_1}x^{s_1}+\ldots +k_{s_n}x^{s_n}$. Then it is immediate, that $h$ has to contain the monomial $-k_{s_1}x^{s_1}$. It is also clear, that the largest exponent of $h$ cannot be in $S$. I have the impression that the above question can be answered negatively, but I just do not know how to prove it.

Has anyone an idea how to prove this?

Thank you in advance for you help!

Comment: In this generality the answer is negative (if you exclude the trivial case $a=1$). For instance, if $S=\{0, s, s+1, s+2, ...\}$, then $ah$ has to contain a monomial with exponent greater than or equal to $s$, and this is in $S$. It could be possible that the answer is positive for some particular numerical semigroup.